# Java - how to interpret char[] array as int?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, sockets, parsing

I'm sending to my Java server from my C++ client buffer of 9 integers. I'm using read(char[] cbuf) function to read this message.

My question is how can I parse/interpret this cbuf as array of integers. In C++ it's easy but in Java I can't use pointers and so on :)

Thanks for help :)

Comment: How would you do it in C++?

Comment: Chars are 2 bytes, ints are 4 bytes. Are you sending 36 bytes, ie. 18 chars, ie. 9 ints?

Comment: Also, which `read(char[])` method are you using? Which class is it defined in?

Comment: Java's `char` is not interoperable with C++'s `char`: in Java, `char`s are 16-bit values; in C++, `char`s are 8-bit values. You can try making a `DataInputStream` and reading `int`s from it by calling `readInt`, but it may not work if the endianness of the client does not match the endianness of the server.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I assume they are trying to use a `Reader` which it seems they should not be (unless they actually are sending these integers as textual data).

Comment: In C++ ?: int second = * (((int *)charbuffer) + 1); // done I think :)

Comment: All the classes with `Reader` in the name are for interpreting input as Strings/characters.  All the classes with `InputStream` in the name are for interpreting input as binary data.  So whatever `Reader` class you're using to read this, swap it for the matching `InputStream` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you reading into a char array? Read into a byte array and use a ByteBuffer from java's nio package..

`ByteBuffer.wrap(my_byte_array).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();`